# how to use ng-if for directive show/hide

Tags: angularjs

i want to show/hide a template. so i am going to acheive this using directives.

Below the code in one template.

```
 <div resupload ng-if="resuploadvisible"></div>
```

i changed the resuploadvisible value to false in directive when close button clicked as below.

```
scope.cancelupload = function () {
                scope.resuploadvisible = false;
};
 scope.openupload = function () {
                    scope.resuploadvisible = true;
    };
```

Popup div is not closing even the **resuploadvisible**  set to false.

Intresting this is if i changed the **ng-if** to **ng-show** popup div is opening & closing without any issue.

What is this weired behaviour? Please explain briefly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}.

When an element is removed using `ngIf` its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored.

The scope created within `ngIf` inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance.

An important implication of this is if `ngModel` is used within `ngIf` to bind to a javascript `primitive` defined in the `parent` scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

To fix it use the `$parent` to access your property on your parent scope:

```
<div resupload ng-if="$parent.resuploadvisible"></div>
```